# solrj query is not working

Tags: solrj

I am writing a simple query that works fine in curl but blows up when using solrj.
Please help...

```
curl stmt:
curl "http://ec2-50-19-33-143.compute-1.amazona/solr/Sharecare_User/select?q=firstName:Blah"
```

Java code:

```
solrServer.setBaseURL(solrServer.getBaseURL() + "/Sharecare_User");
  SolrQuery solrQuery = new SolrQuery();
  solrQuery.setQuery("firstName:Blah");

  QueryResponse rsp = null;
  try {
    rsp = solrServer.query(solrQuery);
  } catch (SolrServerException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

and finally the error:

```
Internal Server Error

request: http://ec2-50-19-33-143.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8098/solr/Sharecare_User/select?q=firstName:Blah&wt=javabin&version=2
```

Answer (score 0):

The port is missing in curl, could you be using different ports? 
Could you show what the curl is getting?